Josephson relations when applied voltage approaches the superconducting gap
The standard Josephson relations are $I = I_0 \sin(\phi)$ and $V = \phi_0 \dot{\phi} / 2\pi$. However these equations break down when $I$ exceeds $I_0$, or when $V$ exceeds $V_\text{gap} = 2\Delta / e$. The plot below from Wikipedia suggests that there is just a smooth transition into the non-superconducting state, but what governs the physics? Are there simple equations that govern this breakdown?

Current (y axis) as a function of applied voltage (x axis).
